# ListBlobsSegmentedAsync doesn't return all blob directories

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a hierarchy-structured blob container with around 12k blobs.

--level1

```
   --level21

         --level211

         --level212

   --level22
```

so currently I have two issues

1. I can not see ListBlobs, even though it occurs in a lot of articles.I know it is weird. but the compiler doesn't pass. https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVnrC.jpg
   I am using c# .netcore 1.1 and WindowsAzure.Storage 8.0, so it should not be version issue.
2. so I am using ListBlobsSegmentedAsync, for instance, there are 80 sub-folders under level21, but this method only returns 10 of them.
   await blobs.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(false, BlobListingDetails.None, 20000, null, null, null);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's the package version issue. For .Net Core, WindowsAzure.Storage 8.0 doesn't have method `ListBlobs`. Update package to latest version(9.1.1), then you will see it.

As for `ListBlobsSegmentedAsync`, I can't reproduce your problem on my side. The maximum you set as 20000, has a limit of 5000 by design, you can try to change it, but on my side it doesn't matter. If you have to use this method, you could show us more details about your code.

Comment: I upgraded to 9.1.1 but still doesn't show, so that's why I give up and use ListBlobsSegmentedAsync. as I commented in Zhaoxing's comment, it is weird but I observed the happening. I already changed my code to repeat the calls until the end but it should not be like this, and to me it is a bug in the library. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Luke I see this method in a console app(.net core) with [Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.0.0) package and the 9.1.1 storage package installed. Could you tell me what kind of project you have created and your .net core package full name?

Answer (score 0):

It's expected that [ListBlobsSegmentedAsync](https://docs.azure.cn/zh-cn/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobdirectory.listblobssegmentedasync?view=azure-dotnet) returns part of the blobs since it's exactly what the method is doing (listing blobs in a **segmented** way, it's not guaranteed to return all the results in one call).

You may refer to [this blog post](https://ahmet.im/blog/azure-listblobssegmentedasync-listcontainerssegmentedasync-how-to/) about how to get all the results with continuation token.

Comment: yes. I understand that it will return partial, but I should be able to control the number of records. otherwise there is no reason to pass 20000 as a parameter. finally I have to call twice to get all 87 records, first call 12 records, and second call 75 records. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Please note that maxresults only defines the max number of returned records, but Azure Blob Storage service doesn't guarantee that it will return as many records as it can in one response. It's even possible that the service returns empty result (no record) with a continuation token (which is used to get next segment).